# Looping through list to print each value from each key in loop

Tags: python

I have put together a script to output all fields from a json file.

I have running into issues getting it to print each `finding` from `highsev` and specifically the `id` field from each finding.

Here is the code:

```
json_object=json.load(f)
vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"] = []
for result in json_object['results']:
    vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"] = [vuln for vuln in result['vulnerabilities'] if vuln["severity"] == "high"]

highsev=vulnsBySeverity["HIGHSEVERITY"]
print("HIGH VULNS were")
for finding in highsev:
    print(highsev[finding]['id'])
```

Its complaining :

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

I think I understand what its saying that `finding` call in the `print()` has to be a `int or slice` im just wondering how i can do that, as `finding` contains this:

```
{'id': 'CVE-2020-15999'}
```

Im simply just trying to loop through highsev and output the value of `id` in a loop.

What might i be doing wrong here? can someone please help

Comment: What does *json_object* look like? What is your expected output?

Comment: Why would printing `finding['id']` not work?

Comment: Im trying to just get the `id` value printed for each iterable in `highsev` . i added `json_object` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already looping through `highsev` with your `for finding in highsev:`

If your highsev list contains dictionaries like this `{'id': 'CVE-2020-15999'}`, you can do this:

```
for finding in highsev:
    print(finding['id'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Dummy mistake on my end.

Comment: Anyway to tell python not to `fail` if it doesnt find a `id` key within the iterable ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change last line to:

```
print(finding['id'])
```

As you are looping through highsev.